# Xamarin How to make a fixed element width and height (button)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I made a button on Android Xamarin.Forms! My goal is to make sure the button width and height remain the same irrespective of device screen sizes! But when I try it on two device there was increment in the width and height.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi3Me.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTLYr.jpg

```
       <StackLayout>
              <Button Text="Click me" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     WidthRequest="140" HeightRequest="80" CornerRadius="15" 
                     BackgroundColor="DarkGray"></Button>
      </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want the elements to be the same physical size on every device?  Or something else?  Every device will have a different screen size, pixel density, scale factor, etc.  To get the same physical size you will need to do calculations that take all of those factors into account.

Comment: Yes!!! I built an android app, so when I test the app on different phone, the buttons widths and heights changes and become too big, please when you check those two images you will see the difference, I am new in xamarin thanks!!!

Comment: Then you are going to need to do what I suggested, manually calculate the size based on pixel density, etc

Comment: How can I do that please??

Comment: Are you asking how to do the math?  There are many resources online about how to do calculations using pixel density

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.displayinfo.density?view=xamarin-essentials

Comment: This alone can't guide me please!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same View size for All devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537177/same-view-size-for-all-devices)

Answer (score 0):

You use the right way to set the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`. But the dofferent screen resolution make it do not be the same. That's why when you try it on two device there was increment in the width and height.

You could take the screenshots for the two devices to check with the same size for the two screenshots. The button would show in same size.

For beauty, I suggest to use adaptive layouts or set the width and height according to the screen size. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/styling-for-multiple-device-resolutions/

Comment: Any update? Have you solved this issue?